# How to ignore 'Certificate Verify Failed' error in perl?

Tags: perl, https, ssl-certificate

I want to access a website where the certificate cannot be verified. I'm using WWW::Mechanize get request. So how would go about ignoring this and continues to connect to the website?

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/lists/activeperl/21645/ has a code example:  BEGIN { $ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0 }

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
use IO::Socket::SSL qw();
use WWW::Mechanize qw();
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(ssl_opts => {
    SSL_verify_mode => IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_VERIFY_NONE,
    verify_hostname => 0, # this key is likely going to be removed in future LWP >6.04
});
```

---

With IO::Socket::SSL earlier than 1.79, see [`PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME`](http://p3rl.org/LWP#ENVIRONMENT).

Comment: This got me on the right track for dealing with Mail::Sender not being able to verify the certificate. I ended up hacking Sender.pm to call IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL with SSL_verify_mode => 0

Answer (score 4):

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( 'ssl_opts' => { 'verify_hostname' => 0 } );
```