# Cannot use REST api of a server using HTTPS in Perl

Tags: perl, api, http, post, https

I have tried so many different code snippets to try to get this working but I cannot for the life of me get it to work. Here is the most up to date piece of code that I have. The error message that I receive is "Can't connect to 172.16.77.247:443"

Please assist me to be able to connect. Thank you!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;


my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $server_endpoint = "https://172.16.77.247/api/reference_data/sets/bulk_load/myDataSet";
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $server_endpoint);

# add headers data to HTTP request
$req->header('Version' => '4.0', 'Accept' => 'application/json', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'SEC' => 'f6a2e2b5-d3f3-4dc2-a51a-5bf65fbec9e7');

# add content to HTTP request body
my $post_data = '["192.168.0.10","192.168.0.11"]';
$req->content($post_data);


# issue HTTP request
my $response = $ua->request($req);

# process response
if ($response->is_success) {
    my $message = $response->decoded_content;
    print "Received reply: $message\n";
}
else {
    print "HTTP POST error code: ", $response->code, "\n";
    print "HTTP POST error message: ", $response->message, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you `wget` this address? Do you have `LWP::Protocol::https` installed?  Is there anything going on with the SSL certificate?

Comment: Can't wget to it, I need to use the 'SEC' authentication token to be able to connect.

LWP::Protocol::https - not sure I have this installed, is it simply a case of installing that and trying again or do I need to modify the code at all?
Thanks

Comment: Not quite - headers are passed _after_ the webserver connection is established. You should be able to wget it, but you might just get a login page or 403. But that's a very different problem to 'cannot connect'.

Comment: I can actually wget to it, oops. my VPN was disconnected which is why I got connection refused beforehand. I am getting an error cannot verify the certificate. Miss-match in certificate name, perhaps this could be the issue?

Comment: Yes, that would indeed be an issue. SSL requires the certificate match the hostname. You could probably fake it (for testing purposes) using a local `/etc/hosts` entry or similar.

Comment: This may help for the cert error, the params in the accepted answer can be passed to LWP:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795030/how-to-ignore-certificate-verify-failed-error-in-perl

Comment: @xxfelixx , Fixed the error by modifying the user agent:

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => {SSL_verify_mode => IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_VERIFY_NONE,
    verify_hostname => 0});

This works as expected, but use strict; has to be turned off. When use strict is on, I get the error

Bareword "IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_VERIFY_NONE" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at GetAssets.pl line 10.

Any ideas how to make this work without turning off strict?

Comment: Add `use IO::Socket::SSL;` should fix the warning.

Comment: got it working?