# How to turn off ssl certificate validation in jmx4perl

Tags: jmx, nagios, icinga

I would like to setup monitoring of our Springboot application. We already have jolokia included in.
I'm not able to connect to jolokia endpoint though due to ssl certificate validation failure.

```
GET https://localhost:9090/jolokia/search/*%3Aj2eeType%3DJ2EEServer%2C*

===========================================================
500 Can't connect to localhost:9090 (certificate verify failed)
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Mon, 07 Dec 2020 13:12:16 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response

Can't connect to localhost:9090 (certificate verify failed)

SSL connect attempt failed error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 50.
```

Thank you,
Radovan

Comment: It could be achieved by setting option as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795030/how-to-ignore-certificate-verify-failed-error-in-perl . Just do not know how to pass through.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try setting this environment variable:

```
PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME=0
```

You don't give an example of what your check command looks like, but as a general example you should be able to squeeze in environment variables at the start of it:

```
define command {
   command_name foo
   command_line PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME=0 /plugins/my_plugin.pl (...)
}
```

This  is one way of setting the variable at run time, you can of course set it in other ways, such as in a systemd service file, but I think this is the easiest and surest way to get it to apply.

Comment: It did not fix the issue. :(
I'm testing locally:
`> jmx4perl https://localhost:9090/jolokia --verbose --user admin --password ...
GET https://localhost:9090/jolokia/search/*%3Aj2eeType%3DJ2EEServer%2C*
Can't connect to localhost:9090 (certificate verify failed)

SSL connect attempt failed error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 50.

500 Can't connect to localhost:9090 (certificate verify failed)`

Comment: You need to supply more information. What is your check command like? What is Nagios configured to do?

Comment: Currently I'm only testing and running the command from the shell not inside the nagios.

Comment: The output you provided doesn't show that you set the `PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME` env variable, did you?